# How many threads should exist in a Java app?

Tags: java, concurrency

As I know, there is a rule:

```
N_threads = N_cores / (1 - blocking_factor)
```

So, on the one hand, if I have a CPU intensive tasks, I should have no more than `N_cores` threads, and on the other hand, if I have an IO intensive tasks I can have as many threads as the blocking factor will allow.

The question:
If, for example, I create two pools for CPU intesive tasks, with 'N_cores' threads in each, than would it break this rule? Does this rule apply to a particular thread pool (and I am allowed to have as many thread as I see fit), or a JVM common pool (and I should apply this rule to the threads that belong to my entire Java process)?

Comment: your question is like this asking such a question: if each woman needs 9 months to born a baby, so is it possible to born a baby with more than more moms sooner? e.g. using 2 moms lets the baby to born in 4.5 months. What do you think about it?

Comment: @epcpu I agree with you, of course. But what should be the rule then? If it applies to JVM itself, how on earth can I control the number of threads?

Comment: This old rule used to apply to the overall JVM. The reality is this rule hasn't really been applicable for years due to hyper threading, hardware virtualization, etc. The best thing to do is to test a specific use case and see what your thread pool sizing  should be set to based on actual expected loads.

Answer (score 0):

So the formula applies nicely for CPU intesive tasks, so if there is no blocking at all you can easily calculate the pool size by the number of cores. If the processing involves varying blocking time for the tasks you have, you may need more flexibility to ensure responsiveness of your app.  ForkJoinPool.ManagedBlocker can be used in cases in which additional threads may be temporarily needed to ensure sufficient parallelism.

check out this course on how it's used: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5M55Ab6LG7A